# QGIS 'Processing_xxx' folder in C:/User/AppData/Local/Temp directory isn't deleted on application exit

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I wrote a Processing algorithm as Python script.

The script chains many `processing.run()` calls; the outputs of most of them are written to disk using the `QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT` syntax for the `'OUTPUT'` value of the argument dict.

As a result QGIS saves these all temporary outputs to the 'processing_xxx' folder created in "C:/User/AppData/Local/Temp", each one in a new separate folder. The process is quite long and the final processing_ folder can be around 10Go.

This 'processing_xxx' folder is supposed to be temporary and discarded when QGIS is closed, except it isn't.

I have read many threads on this subject and it seems the issue was signaled (and apprently addressed?), here's the most relevant link I could find so far : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33641, several gis.stackexchange entries point to it. It says the issue was fixed in the 3.12 version with Windows 10.

I tried the 3.14 and 3.16 releases and the folder still isn't discarded on exit on my computer; I have windows 10 installed.

I can manually delete the files by going to the 'processing_xxx' folder after QGIS was closed.

Am I doing something wrong? Is anybody else facing the same issue? Would cleaning these temporary files by adding a few lines at the end of the script be a viable solution?

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue, I tried some QGIS interpolation tools, like Triagulated Irregular Network (TIN), and got a Windows Lower Disk Space error notification, and I found my computer's `C:/User/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_xxx` folder was around 78 GB. I just delete it manually, I use QGIS version 3.6.2 on  Windows 10.